# Why is Sentinel-1 using geographic coordinate system and Sentinel-2 projected one?

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, utm, sentinel-2, sentinel-1

I was wondering if there's any particular reason for Sentinel-1 to be georeferenced to WGS '84 (a geographic coordinate system), while Sentinel-2 is using UTM (a projected coordinate system). I couldn't find any justification online, so my initial thought was that this might be the case in order to avoid distortion of the visualization when viewing within a GIS software.

Comment: I am not sure but one reason for this could be that Sentinel-1 data underlies stronger topographic distortions. In order to remove them, a DEM is used (orthorectification based on Range Doppler). As most globally available DEMs come in WGS84, this avoids the need for reprojection or resampling of the elevation data. 
At least this is how I interpret the "Ground Range Detected" section here: https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-1-sar/product-types-processing-levels/level-1